# Wcf service breaks on custom object

Tags: c#, wcf

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISystem
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();

    [OperationContract]
    string Stuff(Foo a);
}

[DataContract]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public class System : ISystem
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }

    public string Stuff(Foo a)
    {
        return a.Bar;
    }
}
```

**Problem**:

When I comment the `Stuff(Foo a)` it will recognize my service in Visual Studio after publishing it online. If I don't comment it, as I need this method it will turn red in visual studio and not recognize the functions or any of them anymore.

Comment: where is your Method List<ServerDisk> GetDisk();?

Comment: @Sajeetharan added, but I doubt it's in there....

Comment: What does break mean, are you getting an exception and if you are what is it?

Comment: If I update the service reference after publishing it to an online environment it won't recognize the service anymore `It will turn red in  VS and not recognize any methods anymore. ` - If I comment the interface line, and update the reference it will work again.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but perhaps try returning an array of ServerDisk instead of a list

Comment: @3dd a single object (not a list, not an array) does not work either.